# How to be able to empty completely a drinking water tank with an outlet not completely at the bottom?

Tags: water-tank

I have a drinkable water tank (precisely to drip water my edible plants with pH 6.5) with outlets on the flank. The 1-1/4" one I use is at 45mm minus half the diameter = 20mm from the bottom, so I cannot empty the tank.

I would like to be able to empty it completely after each use. I have set it up on a double slope, but it is not enough, I need to fill the inside first 20mm.

These solutions are not satisfactory:

- small stones let gaps
- concrete is very heavy and toxic
- standard resins are toxic
- food resin are very expensive, I would need 9 liters for a cost of 250€, and I am not sure it is completely safe
- plaster? Won't it disintegrate with my pH 6.5 water?
- 20mm polystyrene or plaster coated with a 2mm layer of food resin, would it be waterproof at contact with the tank walls? Does this last one with plaster alright?

Other solutions without filling the inside:

- use an immersible pump is complex because I have to bring electricity

What else?

[image]

Comment: Change the tank for one with a bottom outlet designed with a conical base so all the water goes out the pipe.

Comment: "concrete is toxic" Ummm, sure, if you eat/drink the concrete. As a cured product, it's artificial limestone conglomerate and a very standard material for large drinking water storage containers and water distribution pipes.

Comment: _Why_ do you need to empty it completely after every use? How big is the tank? Could you just tip it upside down to empty it through the fill hole in the top? There's more going on here than you're telling us...

Comment: "standard resins are toxic" you misunderstand the epoxy process. It's like taking hydrochloric acid (very toxic) and sodium hydroxide (very toxic) and mixing them together in correct proportion, you get table salt and water (and boom).  With epoxy, "B" is grabby and thus toxic, but the end result (mixing for a slight surplus of A) is long molecules of A-B-A-B-A-B-A-B-A (A on both ends).  That molecule is non-toxic for most types of epoxy.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite enough information - tank material, flanged joints, etc?

However, If at all possible, make another tap-hole right at the bottom, and use that. Or, cut a hole which did go level with the bottom of the tank, and use an inspection hatch in its place - not a bad idea for clearing out accumulated crud anyway! Could easily be be as big as 3-4+" diameter, to get a brush in.

Or attach tubing to the internal section of the original tap, which bends downwards to reach the inside bottom of the tank. This would form a syphon when there was, say, a couple of inches of water left in the tank, so the whole could be drained from that time, through the original tap.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph, which is how to do this if not simply getting a different tank as Solar Mike suggests. Inlet tube (bent, rigid, angle-cut) that scavenges the bottom.